# Box and text issue

Tags: css, text, grid, styles, box

I tried everything I knew but I didn't understand what I was getting through. I want the texts to stay inside the box and go to the bottom line when it reaches the border of the box. Thank you in advance.

[Here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZvdw.png)

Comment: Please include a [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper{
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding:1rem;
}

p{
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height:100px;
    background-color: white;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Loremipsum,dolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelit.Corporisarchitetorepellendusducimus,obcaecatiremeveniet,laborequisquamrationevelmodiveniamadipisciimpeditquodrerumquasi.Atquedoloribusaut vi</p>
</div>
```